# How do I override a JS function in js/varien/product.js?

Tags: javascript, magento

I am making a Magento extension that calls a custom JS file on the product view page. This custom JS file will load last and needs to override the formatPrice() function found at the bottom of /js/varien/product.js.

The original formatPrice function is as follows:

```
formatPrice: function(price) {
return formatCurrency(price, this.priceFormat);
}
```

I would like to replace / override this function with the following:

```
formatPrice: function(price) {
if (price % 1 == 0) { this.priceFormat.requiredPrecision = 0; }

return formatCurrency(price, this.priceFormat);
}
```

How do I write the JS code in my custom JS file so that it will properly override this function? I'm not familiar with JS enough to know.

Comment: What object is `formatPrice` a property of? Is it global?

Comment: Like bfavaretto said: It depends on where `formatPrice` is defined.

Comment: I believe it sits inside Product.OptionsPrice.prototype. An object is created with this prototype using the line `Product.OptionsPrice = Class.create();` immediately preceding the declaration of Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is global then you can just do `window.formatPrice = myNewFormatPrice;` if it is a member of an object then you would do something like: `anObject.formatPrice = myNewFormatPrice;`

If you need to edit the prototype of an object use: `Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.formatPrice = myFormatPrice;`

Also you need to look into the access to `requiredPrecision`. If it is "private" or "protected" then you won't be able to access it.

Comment: OK, I got it: `function myFormatPrice(price) { if (price % 1 == 0) { this.priceFormat.requiredPrecision = 0; } return formatCurrency(price, this.priceFormat); } Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.formatPrice = myFormatPrice;` Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

While @jholloman's answer is correct from a functional standpoint, you might consider doing this the Prototype's way, inheriting from `Product.OptionsPrice` and using *that* new class instead. This is from `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`, line 36 (where I presume you need it changed):

**Original**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
```

**Modified**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyOptionPrice = Class.create(Product.OptionsPrice, { // inherit from Product.OptionsPrice
        formatPrice: function($super, price) { // $super references the original method (see link below)
            if (price % 1 === 0) { 
                this.priceFormat.requiredPrecision = 0; 
            }
            return $super(price);
        }        
    });
    var optionsPrice = new MyOptionPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>); // use yours instead
</script>
```

**Using [wrap()](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/wrap/)** (this way, you don't have to change the original method name):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.formatPrice = Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.formatPrice.wrap(function(parent, price) {
        if (price % 1 === 0) { 
            this.priceFormat.requiredPrecision = 0; 
        }
        return parent(price);        
    });
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
```

See [this link](http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance) about Prototype's inheritance and the **$super** var.
Again, I saw code similar to @jholloman's suggestion used in Magento, so there's no problem going his way, but I thought you might want to know how to do this Prototype's way.

Comment: Thank you. I can appreciate the rationale for this approach.